# Can django-userena replace pinax?

Tags: django, pinax

i am creating a django video sharing project, I need user accounts, gravatars etc.

I tried [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/), i wanted to use the pinax social, but they don't offer that project anymore.
I was thinking of using the accounts app, but [django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) seems better, so i created a `project zero` with pinax and tried to integrate django-userena with it. But is it easier **for me** to actually download [django-userena demo](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/tree/master/demo_project) and use it as a starting point, instead of using pinax. So does pinax offer anything that i can use beside the account management which **userena** offers? And thus, **can userena replace pinax?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about pinax. But I can tell you that I use django-userena and it is really a great package. It comes with the templates so you can already start with the demo they provide as a starting point. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) has a lot of other projects and apps besides it's account management ones. Django-userena is specifically for profiles and accounts. Pinax's account-management app and project are what should be compared here. Both are similar ways of doing the same thing, so it's really up to personal preference. I prefer pinax because there are many other apps besides just account management that I can download bundled as a project.